# How to clean up mlcp archive data from local

Tags: marklogic

I have a strange problem that I could not permanently free up ML archive files from my local laptop.

Those archive files are organized in different folders and are generated with MLCP export archive mode. (I use the MLCP import from the archive to quickly swap different datasets for XQuery development.) Over time some archive data are no longer required. However, even if I have deleted some archive folders from the system, whenever I run MLCP import with archive mode for any existing archive, those deleted archive folders with archive data will also get restored to the local laptop.

Even more interesting, if I delete the archive folder and reboot my laptop.
When I first launched my VSC, those deleted archive folders were indeed not there initially.
However, as soon as I start up my docker desktop, those deleted archive folders will reappear. That means those ml archive files are never permanently deleted.
[image]

My gut feeling is that this problem must be related to the docker desktop...
But I could not explain the root cause.

My question is how to clean up mlcp archive data from my local development PC.

Here is my local ML development set-up.

- Windows 11
- visual studio code
- docker desktop (ML docker image)